# Exponential pop. growth when only given population at two instances of time.

Tags: exponential-function

I have a problem where I'm only given the population of a "bacteria culture" at two instances in time: 2 hours and 4 hours.  The problem says the population of bacteria is 125 after 2 hours, and 350 after 4 hours.  It specifically says the bacteria in the culture increases according to the law of exponential growth.

I know the formula $y(t) = y_{0}e^{kt}$ where $k$ is the growth constant (and $t$ is time, of course).  I know how to find k if you're given the initial population, or time.  But in this case, I'm not sure what to do.  It asks to find the initial population, then write the exponential growth model.  I know how to write the growth model once I find the initial population, because then I can solve for $k$.  But I just don't know how to find $k$ when given only two populations at given points of time with exponential growth.  Can anyone help?

Comment: After thinking more, I think it might be possible to write a system of equations: $125 = y_{0}e^{k(2)}$ and $350 = y_{0}e^{k(4)}$ and then this would solve for both k and the initial population simultaneously.  Is this the right approach?

Comment: Just as a "cultural" remark, it is an interesting characteristic that just as two points determine a line, two points also determine an exponential curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_0$ be the initial population, and let $k$ be the growth constant. Then the population at time $t$ is $y_0e^{kt}$.

Putting $t=2$, we get $y_0e^{2k}=125$. Similarly, $y_0e^{4k}=350$.

Divide. We get $e^{2k}=\frac{350}{125}$.

Now that we know $e^{2k}$, we can find $y_0$. And now that we know $e^{2k}$, we can find $k$ by taking the logarithm.

**Remark:** I see that you saw how to approach the problem. If you wish to weite up your conclusions as an answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: Thank you very much that helps.

Comment: No, I tried my method but it didn't work, well at least I must have done the Algebra wrong.  Your explanation is more clear, no need to delete it.

Comment: You are welcome.  If there any step that you have trouble completing, please leave a message.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of variety, without using template formulas, you can think in the following way. Exponential growth is about *multiplying* by some common growth factor every unit of time. We could call that growth factor $b$. So here, after two hours, we went from $125$ to $350$. that means $$125\cdot b^2=350$$ from which you can solve for $b$ and find that the growth factor is $\sqrt{\frac{350}{125}}$.

Now what was the original population? Well moving backwards in time two hours:
$$125\div\left(\sqrt{\frac{350}{125}}\right)^2=\frac{125^2}{350}$$ So the population at $t$ hours after the initial moment is $$P(t)=\frac{125^2}{350}\left(\sqrt{\frac{350}{125}}\right)^t$$

Comment: Hey, this is a really cool way to think about it.  Thank you for the insight.